# How do you form the matrices for Quadratic Programming in Matlab

Tags: regression, matlab, regularization

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01511) paper, Gaines and Zhou suggest solving for $\beta$ in constrained lasso by the following quadratic program form:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
 &\text{minimize}& \quad \frac 12 \begin{pmatrix} \beta^+ \\ \beta^- \end{pmatrix}^T \begin{pmatrix} X^T X & - X^T X \\ -X^T X & X^T X \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \beta^+ \\ \beta^- \end{pmatrix} + \left( \rho 1_{2p} - \begin{pmatrix} X^T y \\ -X^T y \end{pmatrix} \right)^T \begin{pmatrix} \beta^+ \\ \beta^- \end{pmatrix} \label{eqn:LS-constrlasso-QP} \\
 &\text{subject to}& \quad \begin{pmatrix} A & -A \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \beta^+ \\ \beta^- \end{pmatrix} = b \nonumber \\
 & & \quad \begin{pmatrix} C & -C \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \beta^+ \\ \beta^- \end{pmatrix} \le d \nonumber \\
 & & \quad \beta^+ \ge 0, \quad \beta^- \ge 0. \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
$$

I'm interested in solving just the traditional lasso in this form. But I'm confused with the splitting of $\beta$ into positive and negative, how would that work for the `quadprog` solver in Matlab? And in the form above, `H` from `quadprog` is equivalent to the matrix of the four $X^TX$ terms. I'm confused, how do I represet these four terms as one matrix?

As a reminder, `quadprog` takes a function of the form $\frac{1}{2}x'Hx + f'x$ and solved for $x$.

Thanks!

Comment: Your optimization variable, i.e., your x, will be a $2p$ by $1$ vector, the first $p$ components representing $\beta^+$, and the last $p$ components representing $\beta^-$. Your H matrix will be `[X'*X -X'*X;-X'*X X'*X]`. You ought to now be able to figure out what your f is and how to enter the constraints.

Comment: So H is shape [2,2] and H[1,1] is $X'X$? That confused me. What does $p$ mean here?

Comment: As on p. 1 of the paper you linked, X is n by p. That makes H 2p by 2p. H is formed by concatenating matrices (that's what I showed), as per MATLAB concatenation rules.

Comment: I see. I will give it a try!